# hiding divs using javascript that don't match the clicked div and pushing correct div up the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, show-hide

I have a web page in PHP that shows blog posts/ articles that were posted from 2015-2008. basically at the top of the page I have buttons that have the year on it, and below all the blog posts and articles correlatin to the years. I want to have a feature so that if the user clicks 2013, all other posts with years not matching 2013 will dissapear and the correct year posts/articles will move up to the top of the page, so the user doesn't have to scroll.

Here is my code, the content is loaded through a controller so the page is basically created by grabbing data from an array.

```
<div class="calendar-key">
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2015" id="btn" ><a href="#2015-1" rel="2015">'15</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2014" ><a href="#2014-1" rel="2014">'14</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2013" ><a href="#2013-1" rel="2013">'13</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2012"><a href="#2012-1" rel="2012">'12</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2011" ><a href="#2011-1" rel="2011">'11</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2010" ><a href="#2010-1" rel="2010">'10</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2009" ><a href="#2009-1" rel="2009">'09</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2008" ><a href="#2008-1" rel="2008">'08</a></div>
<div class="cd-timeline2-img cd-2007" ><a href="#2007-1" rel="2007">'07</a></div>
```

```
<?php foreach ($article as $slug => $article): ?>

    <div class="cd-timeline-block">
        <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-<?php echo $article['year'] ?>">
            <span class="timelinedate"><?php echo $article['month'] ?><?php echo $article['day'] ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="cd-timeline-content">
            <a href="<?php echo $article['link'] ?>">
                <h3 class="press_title" id="<?php echo $article['year']  ?>-<?php echo $article['first']  ?>"><?php echo $article['title'] ?></h3>
                <img src="<?php echo $article['image'] ?>" width="100%" height="auto" />
            </a>
            <p><?php echo $article['description'] ?> </p>
            <div class="social-share-buttons article-share-buttons pull-left">
                <a class='social-email' href='<?php echo SocialShareLink::email("", "Check out this article, ".$article['title']." \n\n" .$article['link']); ?>'</a>
                <a class='social-facebook' href='<?php echo SocialShareLink::facebook($article['link']); ?>' target='_blank'></a>
                <a class='social-twitter' href='<?php echo SocialShareLink::twitter("", $article['link']); ?>' target='_blank'></a>
                <a class='social-google' href='<?php echo SocialShareLink::googleplus($article['link']); ?>' target='_blank'></a>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php echo $article['link'] ?>" class="cd-read-more" title="Read More" target="_blank">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the for each basically takes an array I have in a config file with data, and populates the articles on the page for however many there are in the array.

```
'articles' => [
    'article#1 example' => [
        'description' => "exampletextblablabla",
        'title' => 'article title',
        'link' => '//www.google.com',
        'year' => '2015',
        'month' => 'Jul ',
        'day' => '25',
        'first' => '1', //first article of that year 
        'image' => '../../images/example.jpg'
    ], 

//more articles in this format
```

and then my failed attempt at js

```
<script type="javascript">
$('.cd-timeline2-img a').on('click',function(){
    var eq = $(this).index();
    $('cd-timeline-img cd-<?php echo $article['year'] ?>').removeClass('show');
    $('cd-timeline-img cd-<?php echo $article['year'] ?>').eq(eq).addClass('show');
});
</script>
```

I am not very good at javascript, so I tried something like this but nothing works. I feel like this is an easy little script to right, any help would be great! thanks.

Comment: I'm going to make a few assumptions for my answer - That the articles are display: none by default because you are only adding/removing the "show" class - so I assume all of the elements have the show class on load. I will post my solution shortly.

Comment: apart from a typo: `cd-timeline-img` versus `cd-timeline2-img` I don't really get what you are doing. You want the articles to be shown/hidden not the buttons, right? Because right now you manipulate the buttons.

Comment: as of right now, no, they aren't, they display "table"

Comment: I'm working on a solution in Fiddle, which is why it is taking me a little longer than usual. This should fix it all. Give me a little bit longer.

Comment: take your time :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo! Finally, I got it working and 100% where I want it. So I used your code and threw it into a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/4Lyofmkh/44/

You will see that I went with my approach - by default, the articles are display none and have a class of 'show' on them to begin with - you will also notice I changed where you had your 'cd-(year)' - I did this because you needed to identify the entire article container since that is what you would be hiding/showing.

I also added a 'Show All' button, so the user can view all if desired.

So like I said I changed your HTML markup right here:

```
<div class="cd-timeline-block cd-2015 show">
    <!-- Article Year in Div Class below -->
    <div class="cd-timeline-img">
```

It was "cd-timeline-img cd-2015" previously. That is the only change you need to make to your markup, besides adding the "show all" button (if you want it):

```
<div class="show-all"><a href="#showall">Show All</a></div>
```

Furthermore, I applied the display:none css property to the ".cd-timeline-block"

```
.cd-timeline-block {
  margin-top:35px;
  display:none;
}
```

Which is why we initialize the page with the "show" class on there:

```
<div class="cd-timeline-block cd-2015 show">
```

Which has the following styles:

```
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

Finally, we get to the meat of it all, the jQuery. I will post the working code that I used and then explain it. The following code is to toggle articles based on the year clicked:

```
$('.calendar-key a').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    var x = 'cd-' + $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.cd-timeline-block').each(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass(x)) {
        $('.cd-timeline-block').not(this).each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('show')) {
                $(this).toggleClass('show');
            }
        });
        $(this).each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('show')) {
                $(this).toggleClass('show');
            }
        });
      }
    });
  })
});
```

As you will see, when a ".calendar-key" link is clicked, the clicked link will produce a variable based on the links "rel" - the variable adds the "cd-" prefix onto the "rel" value. Then for each ".cd-timeline-block" if it has the class that was created from clicking (the variable just discussed), it will cycle through all of the ".cd-timeline-block" elements that isn't "this" (meaning all elements that don't match the selected year.) - for all of those elements, if it has the "show" class, it will be toggled. Then the last part, it takes the "this" and cycles through each of them, if it doesn't have the class "show", then it toggles the class "show", thus displaying the desired elements.

Finally, the show all button is controlled with the following function:

```
$('.show-all a').on('click', function() {
  $('.cd-timeline-block').each(function() {
      if(!$(this).hasClass('show')) {
          $(this).toggleClass('show');
      }
  });   
});
```

Its a fairly simple function. When the ".show-all" link is clicked, it cycles through all of the ".cd-timeline-block" elements, again, if they don't have the "show" class, the function will toggle the "show" class.

I know that was a lot but hopefully it all made sense. Again, here is the associated Fiddle I made to help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/4Lyofmkh/44/

Let me know if you need any further help.

**Latest Update:**

https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/4Lyofmkh/46/

Fiddle now contains new mark-up for easiest solution to updated issue marked in comments below.

Comment: Btw, the margin on the ".cd-timeline-block" was simply for demo purposes, you don't need that.

Comment: hey also, I know I marked it correct, but when I click like, 2015, or something, it only displays 1 of the posts, even if there are like 10 posts from 2015 for example. know how to solve that?

Comment: Yeah give me a little bit to incorporate the updated solution - I'm at work and will get to it when I can.

Comment: @anthony - Would it be appropriate to just have the "<div class="cd-timeline-block cd-2015 show">" act as your "year" container, then all you would have to do is add another wrapper around each article. So you would have - <div class="cd-timeline-block cd-2015 show"> then <div class='article-one'></div><div class='article-two'></div></div> - Make sense? That's probably the simplest solution, I can whip up an example.

Comment: ok that does make sense, but then given my code, what should I make the for each loop be then to generate it the way you have it? I basically have a foreach loop create the entire page that pulls from an array, as shown in my original code.

Comment: Can you provide your foreach statement? @anthony

Comment: check the original question, the for each is there, and I added the example array data which the foreach loop uses and populates the page. 
<?php foreach ($article as $slug => $article): ?>

Answer (score 0):

It finally dawned on me that I was filtering your list of years not your posts.  For future reference post a snippet of actual code, now bits with php all over them.  Now the script looks for the rel attribute in your year list for the year, matches that year to the class "cd-year" in each post and filters as necessary.  I stripped out all of the superfluous parts of the post like the social links as they're not needed for this exercise.

http://jsfiddle.net/1dyocexe/2/

```
//this is where you'd have your <?php echo $article['year'] ?> set the current year
var year = 2014;
getPosts(year);

function getPosts(year) {
    $(".cd-timeline-block").find("div").each(function (i) {
        var elm = $(this);
        var cdYear = "cd-" + year;
        var use = elm.hasClass(cdYear);

        if (use === true) {
            elm.show();
        } else {
            elm.hide();
        }

    });
}

$(".calendar-key div a").on("click", function () {
    var year = $(this).attr("rel");
    getPosts(year);
});
```

Comment: So this definitely is what I want it to do but I'm having trouble making my specific example work. 

I need to basically check for this part of the code and I don't know how to do that in the js

        <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-<?php echo $article['year'] ?>">

since all the posts are generated with php, how do I match the year ?

Comment: I'm working on what you're asking for - I'm just stuck at one part that I can't figure out. And I'm running out of time - I might have to post what I have then continue working on it when I get home.

Comment: So here's another example where a year is set hiding all of the irrelevant posts on page load.  http://jsfiddle.net/1dyocexe/1/
I feel like I should also point out that once the page is loaded, the PHP is irrelevant.  Javascript just works on the DOM of the page that exists.

Comment: so if I wanted this code to work with mine, what do I put instead of 'calendar-key' and 'div a' ? cause in the fiddle this is hiding the buttons I have in place.

Comment: I've edited my post now that I understand that "cd-timeline-block" contains the posts you want to filter.